# How to reuse local storage for AJAX page filter

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am struggling with local storage.  I have a mysqli driven list of options that can be filtered with AJAX tick boxes.  I can see local storage is being used, but I have two sets of check boxes and both local storage values are updated the reflect the most recent choice.  That's the first issue.  The second is when you click into the detail of one of the options you hit a new page.  I have no idea how to use the local storage key/value pairs when the browser returns from the detail page to the main AJAX driven page.

Main page:

```
var colour,brand;
$(function(){

    localStorage.clear();

    $('.item_filter').click(function(){
        $('.product-data').html('<div id="loader" style="" ></div>');

         colour = multiple_values('colour');
         brand  = multiple_values('brand');

        $.ajax({
            url:"test-search.php",
            type:'post',
            data:{colour:colour,brand:brand},
            success:function(result){
                $('.product-data').html(result);

            }
        });


        var colour = $(this).serialize();
        var brand = $(this).serialize();
        localStorage.setItem("whatever", JSON.stringify( colour ));
        localStorage.setItem("whatever2", JSON.stringify( brand ));


    });

});


function multiple_values(inputclass){
    var val = new Array();
    $("."+inputclass+":checked").each(function() {
        val.push($(this).val());
    });
    return val;
}
```

...with checkboxes like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<input type="checkbox" name="bl2" class="item_filter colour" value="blue">
</a>
```

then test-search.php

```
$colour="";
$brand="";
$colour = isset($_REQUEST['colour'])?$_REQUEST['colour']:"";
$brand = isset($_REQUEST['brand'])?$_REQUEST['brand']:"";
```

Any advice on how to achieve either of these things would be really appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You don't seem to actually retrieve anything from localStorage. On document load, use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"))` and process the retrieved data. There is also no reason to call `localStorage.clear();` on document.ready, as all this will do it delete any stored data.

Comment: Also, make sure you validate the data in your PHP script! localStorage can easily be edited clientside, and directly stuffing it into a SQL query is a big XSS risk.

Comment: Thanks @BerryM. good advice on the validation.  I understand that I use JSON.parse to bring the info back, but I don't know how to plug that into what I already have.  So if localStorage.getItem exists then JSON.parse else $('.item_filter').click(function(){.  But everything I have tried throws up an error.

Comment: what kind of error ? have you console.log some var to check what it return in your browser? Is the php file work correctly ? can you console.log(result) just before this line  $('.product-data').html(result);?

Comment: I can get colour and brand from localStorage and save them as variables.  Trying to use them in the ajax request, if I say, if localStorage exists, how do I put them into this line: data:{colour:colour,brand:brand}, the test.search.php gives an implode() error, so I'm clearly not passing the variables to that data line. I am guessing this line from the version without localStorage is important?: colour = multiple_values('colour');

Comment: I have got this working.  The code is probably awful, but I can live with it for now.  Thank you for the suggestions.